# Get tokens with CountVectorizer from sklearn using multiple separators

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to use these separators to split sentence to tokens (whenever Python sees some of those chars I want to split sentence there):

`` {""/%»…l¦>|=!—\+([„:<#•}‘°_–·˘“›;^$®&”’){€*?.`@«ľ]~} ``

Here is an example of sentence i want to split in tokens and count occurences for each one:

`@itkutak (pitanje za intesu: radi li ?neka)`

Tokens I would like to get: `itkutak`, `pitanje`, `za`, `intesu`, `radi`, `li`, `neka`
How to use `CountVectorizer` to get this?

This is how my code looks right now:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
cv=CountVectorizer(min_df=0, max_df=1.0)
post_textCV= cv.fit_transform(post_text)
df=DataFrame(post_textCV.A, columns=cv.get_feature_names())
print(df.head)
```

Comment: CountVectorizer from sklearn?

Comment: Yes, from sklearn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are talking about sklearn's `CountVectorizer`. According to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), you can either

1. Define the `token_pattern` parameter. If you know most of your tokens are alphanumeric you can always do something like this

   ```
   vectorizer = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=u'(?u)\\b\\w+\\b')
   ```
2. Overwrite the `tokenizer`, by writing a function that takes a string to do the tokenization yourself. This is usually much slower compared to the first method though.

   ```
   def tokenizer(document):
       pass

   vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenizer)
   ```